# Angular 6 ng build --prod not creating dist folder

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

Hi I am new to angular 6, I am trying to put my angular 6 app to server, I was going through the documentation provided in angular.io website documentation which says I have to do ng build --prod which will create /dist folder and I need to copy that folder into server, but in my case /dift folder itself is not creating when I make ng build --prod, Thanx.

```
ng build --prod

Date: 2018-11-02T09:05:15.509Z
Hash: 73a702a04d7ddf767a38
Time: 33823ms
chunk {scripts} scripts.0f47d3fbd6308206eae4.js (scripts) 599 kB  [rendered]
chunk {0} runtime.a66f828dca56eeb90e02.js (runtime) 1.05 kB [entry] 
[rendered]
chunk {1} styles.0dacd1919fea938bb6af.css (styles) 424 kB [initial] 
[rendered]
chunk {2} polyfills.47128b287f32f00ed880.js (polyfills) 130 bytes [initial] 
[rendered]
chunk {3} main.179049c6a74691736097.js (main) 128 bytes [initial] [rendered]
```

angular.json

```
{
 "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
   "newProjectRoot": "projects",
   "projects": {
    "incident-management": {
     "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
       "projectType": "application",
       "prefix": "app",
       "schematics": {},
  "architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist/incident-management",
        "index": "src/index.html",
        "main": "src/main.ts",
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
        "assets": [
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/assets"
        ],
        "styles": [
          "node_modules/@clr/icons/clr-icons.min.css",
          "node_modules/@clr/ui/clr-ui.min.css",
          "src/styles.css"
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "node_modules/@webcomponents/custom-elements/custom-elements.min.js",
          "node_modules/@clr/icons/clr-icons.min.js"
        ]
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
          ],
          "optimization": true,
          "outputHashing": "all",
          "sourceMap": false,
          "extractCss": true,
          "namedChunks": false,
          "aot": true,
          "extractLicenses": true,
          "vendorChunk": false,
          "buildOptimizer": true
        }
      }
    },
    "serve": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
      "options": {
        "browserTarget": "incident-management:build"
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "browserTarget": "incident-management:build:production"
        }
      }
    },
    "extract-i18n": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
      "options": {
        "browserTarget": "incident-management:build"
      }
    },
    "test": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
      "options": {
        "main": "src/test.ts",
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
        "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
        "styles": [
          "src/styles.css"
        ],
        "scripts": [],
        "assets": [
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/assets"
        ]
      }
    },
    "lint": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
      "options": {
        "tsConfig": [
          "src/tsconfig.app.json",
          "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
        ],
        "exclude": [
          "**/node_modules/**"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
},
"incident-management-e2e": {
  "root": "e2e/",
  "projectType": "application",
  "architect": {
    "e2e": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
      "options": {
        "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
        "devServerTarget": "incident-management:serve"
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "devServerTarget": "incident-management:serve:production"
        }
      }
    },
    "lint": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
      "options": {
        "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
        "exclude": [
          "**/node_modules/**"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
 }
 },
 "defaultProject": "incident-management"
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
 "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
   "baseUrl": "./",
   "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
"sourceMap": true,
"declaration": false,
"module": "es2015",
"moduleResolution": "node",
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
"experimentalDecorators": true,
"target": "es5",
"typeRoots": [
  "node_modules/@types"
],
"lib": [
  "es2017",
  "dom"
]
```

}
}

Comment: This information is not enough for helping you. You need to show your .angular-cli.json or .angular.json file depending on your version.

Comment: Are you sure it's not creating a `dist` folder? There are no errors, so there's no reason for it to be missing.

Comment: @ user184994 Thanks, so like if there is error it wont create is it?

Comment: @ cenk ebret thanks I have updated my question with files

Comment: from which path you are running this command. 
No error is in angular.json. I replaced provided angular.json with mine. And checked.

After removing the 
``"styles": [
          "node_modules/@clr/icons/clr-icons.min.css",
          "node_modules/@clr/ui/clr-ui.min.css",
          "src/styles.css"
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "node_modules/@webcomponents/custom-elements/custom-elements.min.js",
          "node_modules/@clr/icons/clr-icons.min.js"
        ]``
The build is working fine. in dist/incident-management

Comment: And removing some lines is also not a part of error. I just didn't installed the dependencies

Comment: I was also facing same issue. I was not able to create dist folder with ng build.
My problem was that it was an ionic project.
It seems, dist folder is not being created for ionic projects.

Answer (score 1):

```
ng build --prod --base-href /portalName/
```

/portalName/ should be your host application name

Comment: Hi is it necessary to give --base-href /portalName/ because angular.io documentation is not saying to do so.. what i want to do is copy the dist folder and save it on server and run ng-serve from there is it possible?

Comment: @vinaykhegde `ng serve` is **only** for dev usage. Once you've built the application (using `ng build`), you will no longer use `ng serve`. Instead, you can use you're server's HTTP server (such as Apache or Nginx) to serve it.

Comment: --base-href /portalName/ means actually you're building it for that portal and also it'll create a dist for that portal